# Printing html from list of elements angular js

Tags: angularjs

Hello I want to print content from an array of objects using angular js. I know that there are a lot of questions like this but there isn't any case where the same problem occurs. I want to print an attribute of an object as html. I use ng-sanitize as seen in many examples and it works fine though i get an error in console.

Here my test case:

```
  <body  ng-controller="myCtrl">

       <div  ng-repeat="widget in widgets track by $index">
           <div ng-bind-html="widget.content">

           </div>
      </div>

    </body>
<script>

var app = angular.module("MainCtrl", ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
   function Widget(){
    this.content='<p>test</p>';
    }

    $scope.widgets=[];

    $scope.widgets.push(new Widget(),new Widget(),new Widget());
    console.log( $scope.widgets);


});
</script>
```

which works fine and print the elements as it should but in the console i get this error:

```
TypeError: c.push is not a function
    at Function.K.$$addBindingInfo (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:78:223)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:252:330
    at ea (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:73:293)
    at D (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:62:190)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:55:105)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:55:122)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:54:249
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:56:79
    at k (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:60:377)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:281:253 <div ng-bind-html="widget.content" class="ng-binding">
```

I use angular 1.4.8

Do you have any ideas why this error occurs or how to solve it?

Thx in advance

Comment: Have you brought in the angular sanitize library?

Comment: @CallumLinington yes, I also included ngSanitize in the module

Comment: I would be tempted to try and remove the track by see if that helps?

Comment: @CallumLinington nothing changes if I remove the track by. The console error remains

Comment: are you minifying it at all?

Comment: @CallumLinington I am sorry but I cannot quite understand you. What do you mean minify. In the example I used the least code I could think to recreate the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100144/discussion-between-callum-linington-and-jmrag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qAF6eneyLCKEegja28yZ?p=preview) to show the problem you are encountering.

Whenever you use angular modules like `ngRoute` or `ngSantize`, it is important that the version of the module match *exactly* to the version of the angular library.  In your case, you were using angular 1.4.8, but angular ngSanitize 1.0.3.

Updating the code to the proper version of `ngSanitize` from the CDN (and using angular.js instead of angular.min.js for debugging) shows that the error does not occur with `ng-bind-html`.

Answer (score 0):

Use correct Versions for .js files... here is the code.... This is running perfectly

this is index.html

```
<html ng-app = "myapp">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>    
    </head>

    <body ng-controller = "myController">
        <h1>Welcome to the Angular</h1>
        {{4/3}}

        <div  ng-repeat="widget in widgets track by $index">
           <div ng-bind-html="widget.content">

           </div>
      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and this is test.js

```
var app1 = angular.module('myapp',['ngSanitize']);

app1.controller("myController" , function($scope){

    function Widget(){
        this.content='<p>test</p>';
    }

    $scope.widgets=[];

    $scope.widgets.push(new Widget(),new Widget(),new Widget());
    console.log( $scope.widgets);

});
```

save these two files in one folder and run.. it gives output perfectly

Answer (score -1):

Found the bug, don't use `ng-bind-html`, that causes the issue.
Use single angular expression inside your html and it'll just work.

However I don't know what causes the issue.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/xiSGVIPXb27GcKRh9yR1